# ts-node import not defined at runtime

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have the following reference `import { STORE } from "../data/store";` It's part of a react project and works as expected.

However I need to run some code separately over STORE and accessed it the same way as it is in the react project, but ran via `ts-node`.  When I try to access `STORE` by `let data = STORE[videoId].labels;`, with `videoId` set as `"home"` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined`.

Might anyone know what I'm missing --- must be something specific to ts-node...? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone arrives on this page because of imports issue, like I did, here's what my problem was:

I had three files : `index.ts`, `File.json` and `File.ts`

In `index.ts`:

```
import { thing } from "./File";
```

was working well in VS Code: I had auto-completion for `thing` and everything.

But when running `ts-node index.ts`, `thing` was undefined!

When I remembered that I had the `json` file, I just renamed `File.ts` to `File.module.ts` and changed the import to:

```
import { thing } from "./File.module";
```

and it was sorted.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the property STORE is undefined..

If you change `import { STORE } from "../data/store";` to `import * as STORE from "../data/store"` does it work?

Comment: yifanwu said "It's part of a react project and works as expected." until run it by ts-node.